# Date from UIDatePicker parses correctly but prints with wrong minutes and year

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I know that dealing with date and time is a tricky thing, but this one really puzzles me.
I have an UIDatePicker ('thePicker'),that I use to set a value in a UITextField for display reasons. Later on, I need the value from the Picker, so in order not to keep on converting dates to strings and vice versa, I need to store the Picker's value as a date. I do as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate * pickertime = self.thePicker.date;
NSString * timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:pickertime];
[(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:selectedTextField] setText:timeString];
NSString *theKey =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", selectedTextField];
[timeTable setObject:pickertime forKey:theKey];
for (id key in timeTable) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@ \n", key, [timeTable objectForKey:key]);
}
```

The above code is executed when the value of thePicker is changed.
What I observe, is that there is a **20 minutes** difference between the value that I store in the 'timeTable' dictionary, and the value displayed by thePicker.

So: thePicker indicates '14' for the hour value, and '30' for the minute value, but timeTable gets

> key: 1, value: 0001-07-08 14:10:28 +0000

However, the value displayed in the TextField is correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the year.

Comment: Why don't you use `setObject:forKey:` which is more "NS(Mutable)Dictionary" that `setValue:forKey:` (which is more generic/KVC). Where did you check the values? Right after?

Comment: @Larme: setObject:forKey: yields the same result. I check the value right after setting it.

Comment: Does `NSDatePicker` have a `date` property?

Comment: @willeke: no it doesn't. I will update my question with a bit more context

Comment: Are you sure this is about `NSDatePicker`, not `UIDatePicker`? `NSDatePicker` is OS X.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/date